# Difference between various SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Errors

Tags: javascript

There is a plenty of SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Errors around. 
And I, as many others, also struggle to understand the meaning and the root cause of my errors (00002efe / 00002ef3 in particular).

Just a few of similar errors that I came across:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f7d, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f7d.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee7, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efe, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efe.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f76, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f76.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78.
```

I would like to learn whether there is a resource (documentation) that explains the difference between these various error codes and what their meaning is.

Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer. This solution certainly doesn't cover every single code but it gets me the info that I was looking for.

Here are the steps that I took:

**Step 1**) (in Win) open calculator and switch to a programmer mode.

[image]

**Step 2**) Select the "HEX" option in the calculator

**Step 3**) Copy the error code from the message. (the error starting with zeros e.g. 00002efe)

**Step 4**) Paste the error code to your calculator.

[image]

**Step 5**) Change to "DEC" option.

[image]

**Step 6**) At this point, you have the decimal value of the error.
I have found two websites that describe the meaning of these error codes.
Now, head to one of these web pages:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385465.aspx

This is what I got as a result of my searches:

```
00002f7d => 12157 > ERROR_INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR
The application experienced an internal error loading the SSL libraries.

00002efe => 12030 > ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED
The connection with the server has been terminated.

00002ef3 => 12019 > ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE
The requested operation cannot be carried out because the handle supplied is not in the correct state.

00002efd => 12029 > ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT
The attempt to connect to the server failed.

00002eff => 12031 > ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET
The connection with the server has been reset.

00002f76 => 12150 > ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
The requested header could not be located.

00002f78 => 12152 > ERROR_HTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE
The server response could not be parsed.
```

Hopefully, this will be handy to somebody.

Comment: IMO, it’s easier to just use [a node REPL or browser’s developer console](https://i.imgur.com/PX6yuvw.png) than going out of your way to use the programmer mode of calc. You just prefix the number with `0x` to specify that it’s hex rather than octal or decimal (leading 0 means octal) and the REPL spits back the decimal version. You can also `.toString(2)` where `2` is the desired base (`10` is default) ;-).